# How do I automatically include PHP in Wordpress excerpt?

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I automatically include the following PHP script in my WordPress posts?

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(); } ?>
```

I am not familiar with PHP and I have assumed that the above is a code from a plugin I am using to show social sharing buttons.

I was hoping someone may have dealt with adding elements into the excerpt automatically before and would have some code I could copy into my child theme `functions.php`?

Comment: Okay, great. So… what's your question?

Comment: This question is wrong on so many levels.. Read [ask] a question. I'm spending as much time on an answer as you did on your quest..., time is up.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've changed to a question!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddToAny Share Buttons` plugin have options `Display at the bottom of excerpts`
or you can add code

```
function add_excerpt_social( $excerpt ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { return $excerpt.ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(array("output_later" => true)); }
    else { return $excerpt; }
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'add_excerpt_social');
```

to your  theme `functions.php` file.

Comment: Awesome! The only issue is that it's only displaying the first social icon and I have selected four (facebook, twitter, G+ and Linkedin).
Any ideas why/how I can fix it?
http://a1pms.co.uk/video-gallery/extensions

Comment: Can you send your module settings printscreen?

Comment: Sure @tokas - http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1823510/f1b49bab99854f3548d3afbec2c498f7

Comment: @Ryan i try same settings at my wordpress and everything is fine. Can you enable error reporting, may be some issue with code?

Comment: At wp-config.php file change `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`